# QueryDsl and @JsonAutoDetect - Q classes not generated

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I figured out that if entity class has @jsonAutoDetect annotation, the Q class not generated,
Here is the example : 
https://github.com/prilia/SpringJpa-Quarydsl-Test/tree/master/JpaSpringQuarydsl

If remove JsonAutoDetect Q classes genereted fine,
Please, how can I use with entity class as json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like these always disable the execution of the ATP plugin and see if your build has other issues.

e.g. https://github.com/prilia/SpringJpa-Quarydsl-Test/blob/master/JpaSpringQuarydsl/pom.xml#L432

`import` is not a valid scope.

Comment: Hello Timo, what version of spring-data-jpa compatible with querydsl version 3.4.1 ? I used 1.3.1.RELEASE and it's couse errors Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLQuery.from([Lcom/mysema/query/types/EntityPath;)Lcom/mysema/query/jpa/JPQLCommonQuery;] with root cause ...

Comment: The querydsl version is defined here http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.data.build%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-data-parent%22